# Ignore 0 values when plotting a datframe using pandas.DataFrame.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

**TLDR - For pandas v1.3.0, how do you make pandas.DataFrame.plot() ignore 0 values in the dataframe?**

Hello,

I've got a large dictionary (`dic`) of values:

```
{"coproporphyrinogen_III_oxidase_family_protein" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80022.41172847459, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 109565.5292508494, 0] ,
 "cytochrome_P450" : [0, 0, 0, 15643.253217093856, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 "GE37468_family_thiazolyl_peptide" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 760.6246839647665, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 "hypothetical_protein" : [0, 0, 32952.62092444429, 0, 41052.30542410287, 0, 0, 0, 29215.114292957904, 15127.317688470914, 19000.012941156958, 0, 80518.43410461365, 0, 4483.395005763978, 0, 69248.50553424042] ,
 "lantibiotic_biosynthesis_protein" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6760.905587633572, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 "lantibiotic_dehydratase" : [0, 0, 102828.39307131906, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 112777.12671640149, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 "methyltransferase" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 148549.07126720005, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7702.547899592544] ,
 "methyltransferase_domain-containing_protein" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4116.349605911563] ,
 "radical_SAM_protein" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 108242.33121516721, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37942.8885972641, 0] ,
 "SagB/ThcOx_family_dehydrogenase" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27293.3417323153, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 "SagB_family_peptide_dehydrogenase" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 85088.27058167473, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 "TetR/AcrR_family_transcriptional_regulator" : [39306.876331474756, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 "TOMM_precursor_leader_peptide-binding_protein" : [0, 79243.4541557674, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 81211.31721145986, 0, 0, 0] ,
 "YcaO-like_family_protein" : [0, 8320.903748554763, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21387.005874550898, 4420.172803998425, 0, 0, 0]}
```

I would like to plot these as a bar graph, with multiple bars per X-axis point.  `dic` is formatted so that the Nth index of each value corresponds to the bars for X-axis point N (N is a protein name).  This means that X-axis point 1 (the bars for protein 1) should have bars of height 39306 coloured for "TetR/AcrR_family_transcriptional_regulator", X-axis point 2 should have a bar of height 79243 (TOMM_precursor_leader_peptide-binding_protein) and 8320 (YcaO-like_family_protein) etc.

Currently, I am doing it this way:

```
X_AXIS = x_axis_labels_list
index = pd.Index(X_AXIS, name= 'my_name')
cmap = 'tab20'
df = pd.DataFrame(dic, index=index)
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(50, 6), colormap=cmap)
ax.set_ylabel('tk score')
plt.legend(title='labels', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I get the following bar chart:

[image: bad_bar_chart]

I would like to have this bar chart so that the zeroes aren't plotted (making my final figure much smaller and hopefully readable).

Can I do this using **pandas v1.3.0** (perhaps by reformatting the data somehow?)?

Thanks for reading!

***EDIT:***

`df` looks like this:

[image: df]

**EDIT 2**

Someone kindly sugested I replace the 0s with Nan's, but this didn't work (I also confirmed that the 0's had actually been replaced as expected):

```
ax = df.replace(0, np.nan).plot(kind='bar', stacked=False, figsize=(5, 6), colormap=cmap)
```

Comment: My opinion problem is with structure of data, if many categories in x, y axis it is problem nice plot.

Comment: Because if use 0 or NaN it is same ouput.

Comment: Yea, its a pain!  Is there perhaps a way to subset the dataframe and plot things on different axis?  I am almost completely ignorant wrt matplot lib/visualisation but that seems like a possible approach...